# Disable iOS 5 Notification Center Gesture in App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm developing a Kiosk-Mode Application and I want to prevent the notification center gesture (swipe down from top). Since the Application isn't distributed using the AppStore private APIs are allowed.

I have skimmed through the `UIKit` class dump but did not find any hints on how to disable it (resp. don't know where to look, tried `UIApplication` and `UIWindow`).

Has anyone tried this yet and had success?

Comment: You might also want to join this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=EuWVi6IpN0_KzzEhC7I-Qw2

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little tricky, cause you are trying to disable native iOS function like all-fingers swipe gesture on iPad and so on. Some people use this method to define different notification center swipe side:

```
statusBarHidden = YES
```

and then you can redefine side:

```
setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

as example.

I think you couldn't find any hacks to prevent iOS notification from showing at all. As last approach you can get some profit from dealing with jaiblroken features on unlocked devices...