# How to disable notification center on iOS using private API?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I have an app which is in foreground and I want to disable notification center UI in it (so a user can't open it). And I am looking for an API (or at least direction of search) to disable notification center UI or prevent a user from opening it.

Couple of important notes:

- I am looking for a way to disable it completely within an app.

  Just setting [status bar to hidden and moving it to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519654/disable-ios-5-notification-center-gesture-in-app) doesn't work for me. It still could be accessed.
- I want just to disable it and don't modify any behavior.

  So, [kiosk mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938571/trying-to-initate-guided-access-from-within-an-ios6-app) does't work for me either.
- Private API (not jailbreak tweaks) are fine.

Comment: You might try swizzling some status bar methods.

Comment: @CodaFi: Interesting idea. However, I think notification center UI isn't status bar thing (even if statusbar is hidden, you still can open notification center). Anyway, I will try it.

Comment: They've got to be detecting touches on that thing somehow.  If you can swizzle the handler into an empty method, then no more notification center

Comment: So, just to be clear, what you want is when you are running one particular app (that app is in the foreground), then the user should have no way to get to the Notification Center UI.  Right?

Comment: @Nate: Actually, this app is in foreground and while I am in this app, I want to disable notification center UI. (I will update the question)